# how to fix 'pylint too many statements'?

Tags: pylint

Is there a way to condense the following code to remove the pylint too many statements error. All this code is contained within a single function: -

```
    selection = input("Enter 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 to start: \n")

    if selection == "1":
        print("\nYou have selected "+"'"+question_data[0][0]+"', let's begin!")

        for key in science:
            print("--------------------------------------------------------\n")
            print(key)
            for i in science_choices[num_question-1]:
                print("")
                print(i)

            choice = input("Enter you answer (A, B or C): \n").upper()
            answers.append(choice)

            correct_answers += check_correct_answer(science.get(key), choice)
            num_question += 1

        player_score(correct_answers, answers)

    elif selection == "2":
        ...................................................

    elif selection == "3":
        ...................................................

    elif selection == "4":
        ...................................................

    elif selection == "5":
        ...................................................

    else:
        print("\nYou entered an incorrect value.Please try again.\n")
        start_new_quiz()
```

the program works as is but it's for a college assignment and I would prefer not to submit with pylint errors.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious way is to create a function for each selection:

```
selection = input("Enter 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 to start: \n")
if selection == "1":
    treat_one()
elif selection == "2":
    ...................................................
elif selection == "3":
    ...................................................
elif selection == "4":
    ...................................................
elif selection == "5":
    ...................................................
else:
    print("\nYou entered an incorrect value.Please try again.\n")
    start_new_quiz()


def treat_one():
    print("\nYou have selected "+"'"+question_data[0][0]+"', let's begin!")
    for key in science:
       print("--------------------------------------------------------\n")
        print(key)
        for i in science_choices[num_question-1]:
            print("")
            print(i)

        choice = input("Enter you answer (A, B or C): \n").upper()
        answers.append(choice)

        correct_answers += check_correct_answer(science.get(key), choice)
        num_question += 1
    player_score(correct_answers, answers)
```

You could also create a dictionary:

```
functions_to_use = {
    "1": treat_one,
    ...
}
function = functions_to_use.get(selection)
if function is None:
    print("\nYou entered an incorrect value.Please try again.\n")
else:
    function()
```

Of if you want to over-engineer it, use getattr:

```
function = getattr("treat_{selection}", error)
function()

def error():
    print("\nYou entered an incorrect value.Please try again.\n")
```